# Basic sql query fails on MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Have fresh install of MySQL 8.0.

Trying to understand why the following fails (Error Code 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax):

```
select name from table_A;
```

But this one works:

```
select a.name from table_A a;
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more details about what goes wrong. Error 1064 includes a message showing the first character of the query that MySQL failed to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) `name` is a reserved word. Try putting back ticks around it.

```
select `name` from table_A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon similar error case (due to identifier `function` which became reserved in MySQL 8.x) and the solution is adding backticks, as mentioned above [1] (sorry I can't put comments yet to the appropriate answer).

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/50391599/10765325